# How to get a file from the Amazon S3 server Laravel?

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

I'm trying to write and download the file to Amazon S3. The file is loaded but I can not get it back:

```
public function testS3() 
{
    $s3 = Storage::disk('s3');

    $url = 'https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/p720x720/12631558_953568381347717_3978737099026165391_n.jpg?oh=9e14f5ea6f8e3a3fc8ffa07095d4c766&oe=57321C9D&__gda__=1463610491_c1f275837b7f5b4d2041597a3d7bb9c8';        
    $file = file_get_contents($url);

    $s3->put('upload/test/file1.jpg', $file);

    // download        
    $contents = $s3->get('upload/test/file1.jpg');        
    dd($contents);
}
```

I get this error:

```
    FileNotFoundException in FilesystemAdapter.php line 58:
    upload/test/file1.jpg
```

Comment: Try logging in to your AWS account and confirm on the S3 page that the file has in fact been uploaded.  If it is there, can you share what permissions it has listed for it?

Comment: I created permission "Any Authentificated AWS User" on bucket. And set "Everyone" Grantee. Still getting the error.
Tell me, can I configure the permissions only on the buсket, not to create permission for each file.

Comment: file permissions: mgalex Grantee. 
Open/Download
View Permissions
Edit Permissions